# how to make custom tableview in which if row is one then tableview also appear as one row table

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my application i am using three table view and data is coming from web service.and in my first table there is only one data come but it shows whole table. After click on that second table appear in which 4 data come and shows whole table.

So i want that if array count is whatever as per that my table reduce/gain size it self.

Here is my Code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(rubrixTbl==tableView) //
    {
        if (str!=nil)

//*******here str is NSString abject.
 {         
            return 1;
        }

        else

        {
            return 0;
        }

    } if (rubrixTbl2==tableView)
 {
        return [rubaricIDarr count];
//*****rebaricDarr is object of nsmutablearray********
    }

    if(rubrixTbl3==tableView)  
  {
        return [table3Array count];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you reload your table ?

Comment: @Rushabh no when i first come to my viewcontroller data is in tableview...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the height of the tableview when ever you know the count for like set tableView Height to countOFTheArrayForTableView * heightOfTheTableViewCell( 44 in normal UITableView). Let me know if you need the code for this.

```
    tbl.frame = CGRectMake(tbl.frame.origin.x, tbl.frame.origin.y, tbl.frame.size.width, [array count]*44);
```

Comment: check edited answer make sure you change 44 with the height of that tableviewCell you have.

Comment: but brother i take string in first table view

Comment: so how to make an array count for that?

Comment: and what should be the return value?

Comment: we have to take str length instead of count.